# Pyglet: get events in the game loop

Tags: python, pyglet

I want to have access to the mouse and keyboard events from the 'game loop'. To do that I use a class that contains a variable called 'lastevent', a method that returns it called 'getevent' and a Pyglet window whose on_mouse_press/release methods are overwritten.

This is the code I use:

```
import pyglet 

class mypygletwindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.winHandle = pyglet.window.Window()
        self.winHandle.on_mouse_press   = self._onPygletMousePress
        self.winHandle.on_mouse_release = self._onPygletMouseRelease
        self.winHandle.on_key_press     = self._onPygletKeyPress
        self.winHandle.on_key_release   = self._onPygletKeyRelease
        self.winHandle.getevent         = self.getevent

        self.lastevent = {}

    def _onPygletMousePress(self, x,y,button,modifiers):
        print 'press', button, (x,y)
        self.lastevent = {'type':'MOUSEDOWN', 'button': button, 'pos': (x,y)}

    def _onPygletMouseRelease(self,x,y, button, modifiers):
        print 'release', button, (x,y)
        self.lastevent = {'type':'MOUSEUP', 'button': button, 'pos': (x,y)}

    def _onPygletKeyPress(self, symbol, modifiers):
        print 'press', symbol, modifiers
        self.lastevent = {'type':'KEYDOWN', 'symbol': symbol}

    def _onPygletKeyRelease(self, symbol, modifiers):
        print 'release', symbol, modifiers
        self.lastevent = {'type':'KEYUP', 'symbol': symbol}

    def getevent(self):
        out = self.lastevent
        self.lastevent = {}
        return out

if __name__ == '__main__':

    w = mypygletwindow().winHandle

    while not w.has_exit:
        dt = pyglet.clock.tick()
        w.dispatch_events()
        w.clear()

        # get events
        e = w.getevent()
        if e != {}:
            print e
        w.flip()
```

At the bottom of the code, I use 'getevent' in the 'game while loop'. The objective is to obtain all the events that occur. However, when the time between a mouse press and its corresponding release is very short, only the mouse release is obtained. I could understand that the 'on_mouse_press/release' methods are called more quickly than the call to the getevent.

How could I get all the events in the game loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyglet
from time import time, sleep

class Window(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, refreshrate):
        super(Window, self).__init__(vsync = False)
        self.frames = 0
        self.framerate = pyglet.text.Label(text='Unknown', font_name='Verdana', font_size=8, x=10, y=10, color=(255,255,255,255))
        self.last = time()
        self.alive = 1
        self.refreshrate = refreshrate

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modkey):
        print('Key Down:',symbol)

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modkey):
        print('Key Released:',symbol)

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        print('Mouse Released:', x, y, button)

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        print('Mouse Down:', x, y, button)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        pass

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        if time() - self.last >= 1:
            self.framerate.text = str(self.frames)
            self.frames = 0
            self.last = time()
        else:
            self.frames += 1
        self.framerate.draw()
        self.flip()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            self.render()
            event = self.dispatch_events() # <-- This is the event queue
            sleep(1.0/self.refreshrate)

win = Window(23) # set the fps
win.run()
```

See if this makes more sense.
It's a claned up version.